# How can I automate the process of copying files from one folder to another in Centos

Tags: centos, directory, file-copy

I have a statistical application which runs every minute and creates charts accordingly.

In order to make these charts available to other users, I need to copy the whole folder containing the charts and paste it to a shared folder where other users can see the contents.

How can I automate this process so that e.g each 5 minutes the files and folders are updated?

Comment: perhaps you don't need to copy those files....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like something which could perhaps be perfectly solved with rsync. In its simplest form it can be called like this

```
rsync sourceFolder destinationFolder
```

Called in a crontab every 5 minute:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/rsync sourceFolder destinationFolder
```

For options, permissions, exlude of special files or directories see `man rsync`.

Comment: I would recommend `rsync -au` as the default options (preserve all attributes and only overwrite older files).

Comment: I agree Gilles, that is the way I use it too on my production systems. :).

Comment: And to be sure that it does not mess up hardlinks and sparse-files: `rsync -auVH`. That became my current standard.

Answer (score 2):

Use a cron job, assuming you have permissions to add one.

crontab -e

```
0-59/5 * * * * cp -r folder1 folder2
```

You might want to use better flags on the cp, such as cp -ur to only update changed files.

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me, but why you need the files to be *copied* there?

If the users are just opening / reading files and don't need to perform activities on them (like multiple users editing the same file, etc)... you could just make a link to the folder, couldn't you? And then, for every new file inside it, your users would have instantaneous access.

try it:

> ln -s /original_folder/logs /shared_folder/logs

and avoid wasting space...

Comment: Some systems do not allow to link across filesystems (and follow the link), for instance Helios Ethershare. So if you perhaps have a published tree with a shared folder a copy could be neccessary.

Comment: In addition to what wolf already said: In Apache-httpd you have to explicitly allow to follow symbolic-links if using such a construction in a web-server. It is off by default to avoid having access in areas where no user should have access to (even ro).